# "The well-known formulas that gives the relation between the generating functions of a sequence and the sequence of its 'tails'"

Tags: stochastic-processes, generating-functions

I'm reading a paper on [Branching Processes and the Theory of Epidemics](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200513798), and the fourth page (p. 262 of the book) the author refers to "the well-known formulas that gives the relation between the generating functions of a sequence and the sequence of its 'tails.'" Well, it's not well-known to me, and when I tried searching for it my results were all clogged up with probability generating functions for heads/tails coin tosses.

Any ideas? My REU group members contributed primarily obscene jokes, so.

Comment: The authors allude to generating functions $g$ and $G$ related by $$g(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ns^n\qquad G(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_ns^n$$ where $$A_n=\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k$$ Indeed, $G(s)$ is not too difficult to write down in terms of $g(1)$, $g(s)$ and $s$. Is this your question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE. In order to get the best quality answers, it would help if you summarised the relevant functions and stated a clear question. As for your REU group members, whatever, just keep doing math.

Comment: @snarski, yup, that's what I'm trying. Wish me luck! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t actually need to know exactly to what he’s referring there, since the calculation that he needs is given in full detail at $(7)$. What he does there is a two-variable version of the following one-variable derivation of the relationship that he has in mind.

Let $\langle a_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a summable sequence with generating function $A(x)$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $b_n=\sum_{k>n}a_n$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
G(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{k>n}a_kx^n\\\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 1}\sum_{0\le n<k}a_kx^n\\\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 1}a_k\sum_{0\le n<k}x^n\\\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 1}a_k\cdot\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}\\\\
&=\frac1{1-x}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1}a_k-\sum_{k\ge 1}a_kx^k\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{1-x}\big(b_0-A(x)\big)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @MissMonicaE: You’re very welcome.